# Stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I am received a "Stack level too deep" error and I am fairly sure that it is being generated from this model. I know it has something to do with a recursive call, but I have thus far been unable to locate it, thanks.

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  belongs_to :user

  # Validations
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => 
  { minimum: 2, maximum: 20 }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\Z/ }
  validates :race, :presence => true
  validates :class, :presence => true
  validates :user, :presence => true

  def self.races
    ["Human", "Dwarf", "Elven", "Orc", "Undead", "Demon"]
  end

  def self.classes
    {
      :fighter => {strength: 4, endurance: 3, dexterity: -2, charisma: -2, wisdom: -2, intelligence: -3}, 
      :thief   => {strength: -3,endurance: 2, dexterity: 4, charisma: 2, wisdom: -2, intelligence: 0}, 
      :magi    => {strength: -3, endurance: -2, dexterity: -2, charisma: 2, wisdom: 3, intelligence: -3}, 
      :ranger  => {strength: -2, endurance: 2, dexterity: 2, charisma: 0, wisdom: -3, intelligence: 0}, 
      :cleric  => {strength: 2,endurance: 2, dexterity: -3, charisma: -2, wisdom: 3, intelligence: 2}
    }
  end

  def set_class(_class)
    _attributes = Character.classes[_class.downcase]
    transaction do
      self.class = _class.downcase
      _attributes.each do |name, value|
        self.name += value
      end
      self.save
    end
  end
end
```

Server log:

```
Started GET "/characters/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-04 01:54:14 +0200
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by CharactersController#new as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.5ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered characters/new.html.erb within layouts/application (38.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 199ms
```

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:

```
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:85:in `'
```

Comment: Can you share the server log generated for this error. Add it in the question.

Comment: dont use `class`. it is a reserved word.

Comment: But I am prefixing it with an underscore

Comment: Not everywhere, you're not. I'll reiterate: don't use `class`. Metaprogramming is used everywhere in Rails and using a reserved keyword as an attribute name is playing with fire.

Comment: `Stack level too deep` basically means you've got an infinite loop

Comment: But what line of code is causing / initiating the loop?  Note that a "validates" validation can cause this error to be thrown on an update - even when the same form and same input works just fine on a create.  Rip your code to shreds to see where and what it is really breaking.  A custom validator solved it in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. you are using `class` as an attribute,
2. you are confusing `:symbols` and `"String".downcase`,
3. you are using `self.name` (attribute) thinking it's a different setter.

### Class

Don't use `class`. It's a reserved keyword.
These lines will leave ruby very confused:

```
validates :class, :presence => true

self.class = _class.downcase
```

Also, I assume that you have a `class` column in your DB table. You should really rename it to something like `character_class` or `rpg_class`.

### Symbols and Strings

Your `self.classes` method returns a `Hash` whose keys are symbols. And yet, later you try to access it using a string:

```
_attributes = Character.classes[_class.downcase]
```

While it's true that `:foobar.downcase` will do nothing, you can't access those values with `"Foobar".downcase`.
To fix that, you could:

- use `Character.classes[_class.to_sym]`
- use an [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-with_indifferent_access)

In any case, that method could be improved by using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).
At the moment you are re-creating a hash of hashes with each call. Instead, you can save it in a variable and create it only the first time.

```
def self.classes
  @char_classes ||= { fighter: { #...
end
```

Or, even better, use a constant:

```
CHAR_CLASSES = { #.....

def self.classes
  CHAR_CLASSES
end
```

### name

I see that you have this validation in place:

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { minimum: 2, maximum: 20 }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\Z/ }
```

which means you have a `name` column in your DB table, and that it's supposed to be a `String` matching a specific format (only letters, between 2 and 20).

With this said, let's have a look at this block of code:

```
_attributes.each do |name, value|
  self.name += value
end
```

In this local scope, `name` is a variable holding a `Symbol` (e.g. `:strength`) and `value` is a `Fixnum`.
When you do `self.name += value`, however, you are assigning the `Fixnum` to the **object attribute** `name`.

I can't see where you define methods like `strength=` or `dexterity=`. I'm assuming they are columns on the table.

In that case, then this should work:

```
self.public_send("#{name}=", value)
# or just 'send' if it's a private method
```

Comment: great response @tompave - esp your detailed explanations of what's going on inside a block. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting the attributes on your character, you need to generate the setter dynamically. You can't call a dynamic method by appending a variable. `name = 'mike'; self.name` will not call `self.mike`.

```
def set_class(_class)
  _attributes = Character.classes[_class.downcase]
  transaction do
    self.class = _class.downcase
    _attributes.each do |name, value|
      self.public_send("#{name}=", value)
    end
    self.save
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the answer I think. If you respond with info on how this goes - it will put us in a better position to help

Comment: As tompave points out too, it doesn't make sense to be downcasing `_class`. If you think it's a string, then you should be calling `#to_sym` on it in order to access your attributes hash. Otherwise, we can just strip out those extraneous calls.